# A differential inequality $\forall x \geq 0:f''(x)-3f'(x)+2f(x)\geq 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

## Problem

Let $f(x)$ be twice differentiable. $f(0)=-1$, $f'(0)=0$ and $\forall x \geq 0:f''(x)-3f'(x)+2f(x)\geq 0.$ Prove $f(x)\geq e^{2x}-2e^x$ holds for $x \geq 0.$

## Attempt

Consider the second order homogeneous linear differential equation
$$f''(x)-3f'(x)+2f(x)=0\tag{1}$$
with the initial conditions $f(0)=-1$ and $f'(0)=0$.
Since its characteristic equation is
$$r^2-3r+2=0,$$
we can solve to obtain the roots
$$r_1=1,r_2=2.$$
Therefore, the general solution of $(1)$ is
$$f(x)=C_1e^x+C_2e^{2x}.$$
Put $f(0)=-1$ and $f'(0)=0$ into it. We have
$$\begin{cases}C_1+C_2=-1,\\C_1+2C_2=0.\end{cases}$$
Hence
$$C_1=-2,C_2=1.$$
We finally obtain the particular solution of $(1)$
$$f(x)=-2e^x+e^{2x}.$$
Notice that
$$f''(x)-3f'(x)+2f(x)=0 \implies f(x)=-2e^x+e^{2x}.$$
But can we from this conclude that
$$f''(x)-3f'(x)+2f(x)\geq 0 \implies f(x)\geq -2e^x+e^{2x}?$$

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $f''(x) - 3 f'(x) + 2 f(x)$ can be written as $(f'(x) - 2 f(x))' - (f'(x) - 2 f(x))$.  Put $g(x) := f'(x) - 2 f(x)$.  We thus have
\begin{equation*}
g'(x) - g(x) \ge 0.
\end{equation*}
Multiplying the above inequality by the integrating factor $e^{-x}$, we obtain
\begin{equation*}
(g(x) e^{-x})' \ge 0,
\end{equation*}
hence 
\begin{equation*}
g(x) \ge g(0) e^{x}
\end{equation*}
for $x \ge 0$.  Since $g(0) = f'(0) - 2 f(0) = 2$, we have
\begin{equation*}
f'(x) - 2 f(x) \ge 2 e^{x}, \qquad x \ge 0.
\end{equation*}
Again, we multiply the above inequality by the integrating factor $e^{-2x}$ to obtain
\begin{equation*}
(f(x) e^{-2x})' \ge 2 e^{-x}, \qquad x \ge 0,
\end{equation*}
and, after integration
\begin{equation*}
f(x) \ge f(0) e^{2x} - 2 e^{x}, \qquad x \ge 0.
\end{equation*}
Substituting $f(0) = -1$ gives the **correct** result:
\begin{equation*}
f(x) \ge {} {\color{red}-}\, e^{2x} - 2 e^{x}, \qquad x \ge 0.
\end{equation*}

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for your editing.

Comment: Is there  a more general conclusion?

Comment: The idea is to use the decomposition $D^2-3D+2I=(D-I)(D-2I)$, where $D=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and $I$ is the identity. It will work for any linear ODE with constant coefficients whose characteristic polynomial has real roots only.